# searching a string in multiple directories from / in Linux in Multiple servers

Tags: linux, string, shell, search, scripting

I want to search for a string in all the directories from a Linux box at root level recursively. I know I can use `grep` but my requirement is to find that string in multiple servers within a script.

I was just trying with this. Can anyone please help further

```
for host in host1 host2 host3
do
    ssh "$host" grep -R "test" / 2>/dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the attempt is to find a given file across all the servers this can be which can be achieved by

```
for host in host1 host2 host3
do
    ssh "$host" find / -name "test"  2>/dev/null
done
```

Edit 1:

In order to find a given string across files in multiple hosts we can try

for host in host1 host2 host3
do
   ssh "$host" find / -type f | grep "test"  2>/dev/null
done

Comment: sorry, this doesn't answer the very specific question "
I want to search for a string". Your answer searches for file names. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks Tandon. actually the attempt is to find a string or strings within all the files recursively under root directory in multiple servers.